# Loop to read values from two files and use them as variables in a curl in shell

Tags: shell, loops

I need to create a loop so I can use values listed in two text files as variables into a curl command.

For example, let say there is a list named destinations.txt that looks like this:

```
facebook.com
pinterest.com
instagram.com
```

And there is another file named keys.txt which includes API keys to make calls to each destination, this file looks like:

```
abcdefghij-123
mnopqrstuv-456
qwertyuiop-789
```

The idea of this loop is to pull this data so I can run 3 curls each using the data coming from  the line  they are. This is an example considering that $destination and $key are the values pulled from  the txt files.

```
curl -k 'https://'"$destination"'//api/?type=op&cmd=asdasdf='"$key"
```

These would be  the expected results:

1st round:

```
curl -k https://facebook.com//api/?type=op&cmd=asdasdf=abcdefghij-123
```

2nd round:

```
curl -k https://pinterest.com//api/?type=op&cmd=asdasdf=mnopqrstuv-456
```

3rd round:

```
curl -k https://instagram.com//api/?type=op&cmd=asdasdf=qwertyuiop-789
```

I've tried multiple times with nested `while`/`for` and `paste`, however, the results are not as expected since data is duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two files using the `paste` command and `awk` command and the call it iteratively using `for loop`:

```
paste "destinations.txt" "keys.txt" > combined.txt
awk '{ printf "https://%s//api/?type=op&cmd=asdasdf=%s\n", $1, $2 }' combined.txt > allCurls.txt

for crl in `more +1 allCurls.txt`
do
echo `curl -k $crl`
done
```

If you want to redirect the output of the `curl` to some file:

```
count=1
for crl in `more +1 allCurls.txt`
do
# use the awk with the variable count, 
#-v count=$count uses the shell variable in awk
filename=`awk -v count=$count 'NR==count{print $1}' destinations.txt`
filename="${filename}_curl_result.txt "
#redirect the curl output to filename
curl -k $crl > ${filename}
count=$((count+1))
done
```

Comment: this is great, works...thank you. one more help please, the result of the curl needs to be saved in a file that matches the name of the destination, for example:
facebook.com_curl_result.txt
pinterest.com_curl_result.txt
instagram.com_curl_result.txt can you please tell me how to save each result with that format?, thank you.

Comment: @Alex I edited the answer to show how to add the output of `curl` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like that :

```
while read -u 4 destination && read -u 5 key; do
  curl -k https://${destination}/blablabal/${key}
done 4<destination.txt 5<key.txt
```

As long as those 2 files are in sync it should work

Comment: hello Andre, it gives me the next error:  line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `4'
./checker.sh: line 7: `done 4 <destination.txt 5 <keys.txt' ... The curl content  includes <>  and other operators so I  put  it in "  "  so is  curl -k https://${list}"/api/?type=op&cmd=<show></show>&key="{key}  thank you.

Comment: @Alex Not sure here, the code works in Bash. There should be no space between 4/5 and < or between < and the filenames. Also, might want to add -r switch to the read commands

Comment: hello Andre, thank you..  this code also works as a charm! ... cheers.